# Excel vba, Opening new Application: Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following vba code. It creates new Excel application and uses it to open a file. Then it MsgBoxes some cell's value in this file.

```
Sub TestInvis()
        Dim ExcelApp As Object
        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        Dim WB As Workbook
        Set WB = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open("Y:\vba\test_reserves\test_data\0503317-3_FO_001-2582480.XLS")

        Dim title As String
        title = WB.Worksheets(1).Cells(5, 4).Value
        MsgBox (title)

        WB.Save
        WB.Close

        ExcelApp.Quit
        Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The problem is that after MsgBoxing it slows down and eventually gives a `Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action` window. Why does it do this? It's not like there are any hard commands being implemented. And how should I deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the Excel instance in `ExcelApp` is waiting for User Input, most likely.

You can try to add `ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False` to skip any pop-ups that might be there.

Also, while troubleshooting add the line `ExcelApp.Visible = True` so you can see what's going on in the second instance and troubleshoot there.

I encountered this problem in the following situations:

- An alert was opened by the Application Instance and it was awaiting user input.
- While opening a file, it was coming up with some message about a crash when the file was previously opened and whether I wanted to open the saved version or the in memory version (although this should happen before the `msgBox`)
- If you run the code multiple times and it crashes, it might have the file open as read only since there's another hidden instance of Excel that locked it (check your task manager for other Excel processes)

Rest assured that in any case the problem is not with your code itself - It runs fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Code that works for me.

You can select the file from FileDialog. In comments You have code that close the workbook without saving changes. Hope it helps.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import(Control As IRibbonControl)
Dim fPath As Variant
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim CW As Workbook



On Error GoTo ErrorHandl
Set CW = Application.ActiveWorkbook
fPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel file, *.xl; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb; *.xlam; *.xltx; *.xls; *.xlt ", Title:="Choose file You want to openn")
If fPath = False Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fPath, UpdateLinks:=0, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

MsgBox("File was opened.")

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'MsgBox ("File was closed")
Exit Sub


ErrorHandl:
MsgBox ("Error occured. It is probable that the file that You want to open is already opened.")
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these methods worked for me.  I was calling a DLL for MATLAB from VBA and a long simulation would pop up that Excel was waiting on another application OLE action, requiring me to click it off for the routine to continue, sometimes quite a few times.  Finally this code worked (saved in a new module): https://techisours.com/microsoft-excel-is-waiting-for-another-application-to-complete-an-ole-action/

The way I used it is a little tricky, as the directions don't tell you (here and elsewhere) which causes various VBA errors, so I add to the description for what works in Excel 365:

Create a new module called "ToggleOLEWarning" (or in any new module, important!) which only contains the following code:

```
Private Declare Function CoRegisterMessageFilter Lib "ole32" (ByVal IFilterIn As Long, ByRef PreviousFilter) As Long

Public Sub KillOLEWaitMsg()  
Dim IMsgFilter As Long
CoRegisterMessageFilter 0&, IMsgFilter
End Sub

Public Sub RestoreOLEwaitMsg()
Dim IMsgFilter As Long
CoRegisterMessageFilter IMsgFilter, IMsgFilter
End Sub
```

Then in your main function, just decorate the long running OLE action with a couple lines:

```
Call KillOLEWaitMsg

'call your OLE function here'

Call RestoreOLEwaitMsg
```

And it finally worked.  Hope I can save someone the hour or two it took for me to get it working on my project.